# Lowercase and Uppercase are the same JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am creating a program that will pull up the first non repeated word within a string. While doing this I bump into a logic problem where I need to count a word in uppercase and lowercase the same but still returns the original uppercase version of the string.

Here's my codes:

```
function firstNonRepeatingLetter(str) {
 // split the array and transform it to lowercase
 str = str.split('');

 // create an obj that will hold the counter of each characters
 let myObj = {};

 // create a new arr for all the char w/ 1 value
 let uniq = [];

 // iterate through the splitted array
 str.forEach((char) => {
    // if the obj contains the same key (char)
   if(myObj.hasOwnProperty(char)){
      // we add 1 to its value
     myObj[char]++;
   }else{
      // otherwise we set the key value to 1 
     myObj[char] = 1;
   }
 });

 // check the obj with 1 value, 
 for(let prop in myObj){
  // and then push the key inside a 
   // new arr with only 1 counter
   if(myObj[prop] === 1){
     uniq.push(prop);
   }
 }

 console.log(myObj);

 // return the first elem in the arr
 return uniq.length !== 0 ? uniq[0] : '';
}

firstNonRepeatingLetter('sTress') // => must return 'T' instead return 't'
firstNonRepeatingLetter('NecEssarY') // => must return 'N' instead return 'n'
```

The object looks like this: `{ N: 1, e: 1, c: 1, E: 1, s: 2, a: 1, r: 1, Y: 1 }`it counts the 'N' and 'n'separately.

Any idea how to retain the actual case without affecting the functionality?

Thanks!

Comment: I got T and N when I ran this in JSFiddle

Comment: yeah, but look at the object. 'N' and 'n' counts separetly. I need to count them as one. It's a bit tricky there.

Comment: `str.forEach((char) => { char = char.toLowerCase();`

Comment: And also after counting them as one, I need to find a way to return the original case when pulling up the final list of array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first way that came to mind is to convert to upper-case for the object property names so that you can count "A" and "a" together, but then in addition to storing the count store the case of the first one found. So within your existing loop:

```
   let upperChar = char.toUpperCase();
   if(myObj.hasOwnProperty(upperChar)){
     myObj[upperChar].count++;                     // add 1 to its count
   } else {
     myObj[upperChar] = { first: char, count: 1 }; // otherwise set count to 1
   }
```

In context with your full code:

```js
function firstNonRepeatingLetter(str) {
 str = str.split('');

 let myObj = {};
 let uniq = [];

 str.forEach((char) => {
    // if the obj contains the same key (char)
   let upperChar = char.toUpperCase();
   if(myObj.hasOwnProperty(upperChar)){         
     myObj[upperChar].count++;                     // add 1 to its count
   }else{ 
     myObj[upperChar] = { first: char, count: 1 }; // otherwise set count to 1
   }
 });

  
 for(let prop in myObj){              // check the obj with 1 value,       
   if(myObj[prop].count === 1){       // and then push the key inside a 
     uniq.push(myObj[prop].first);    // new arr with only 1 counter
   }
 }

 console.log(myObj);

 return uniq.length !== 0 ? uniq[0] : ''; // return the first elem in the arr
}

console.log(firstNonRepeatingLetter('sTress')); // => must return 'T' 
console.log(firstNonRepeatingLetter('NecEssarY')); // => must return 'N'
console.log(firstNonRepeatingLetter('Stress')); // => must return 't'
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you convert the all the characters of the string to either lowercase or uppercase first.

```
var res = str.toLowerCase();
```

That way it won't count the characters separately.

Comment: If I do this, how can I gain back the original case when pulling it up in the uniq array created above.

Comment: Edit your question to show what will the ideal output look like for NecEssarY